# Recommended AWS EC2 instance type for Zookeeper?

Tags: amazon-web-services, instance, apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

Do you have any suggestions about instance type for zookeeper deployed on aws?
Btw, I use zookeeper mainly for ClickHouse, which means zookeeper is used to transmit metadata and log things (with autopurge set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use HDD. EBS GP2 is OK.

You need at least 4GB for normal ZK work (without OOM every day) -- EC2 a1.large/c4.large (with swap 16GB)

ZK is in-memory DB. So if your ZK DB (snapshot) is 100MB then 4GB is ok if it's bigger you need more memory.
So EC2 large or xlarge.

Comment: Many thanks. And it would be very grateful if you could tell me the recommended instance type for the clickhouse node.

Comment: It depends of data size, queries and response time requirements. CH likes memory. It needs 8GB for a minimal production (with swap). A real big data (billions rows a day into wide table -- hundreds of columns ) needs at least 64GB. Make a POC with c4.xlarge and weekly data and grow the instance if it's not enough. Use EBS GP2.

Comment: Btw, I specify a load balancer host/port in the <zookeeper/><node/> setting and let it choose to connect to 3 actual zookeeper nodes, or just specify 3 actual zookeeper node domains in <zk/><node/> setting. Which way do you think is better? Thanks ^^

Comment: I use one dns name (with 3 ip / 3 zk servers). Never had any issues. All 3 ZK 
servers are used.   ```  <zookeeper>
        <node>
            <host>zoo1</host>
            <port>2181</port>
        </node>
    </zookeeper> ```